# Mathematica 12.3.1 CapForm does not work with ContourStyle anymore?

Tags: plotting, style, compatibility, graphics

Just upgraded to 12.3.1 from 12.1.

In 12.3.1,

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Dashing[{0, Medium, Medium, Medium}], 
   CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[2.]]]
```

now produces

[image]

whereas before the edges of all the dashes (long and short) would be rounded. This is the result from 12.1:

[image]

**Note:** Simply pasting the 12.3.1 output into a 12.1 notebook makes the line caps rounded.

---

I tried searching the documentation, but I can't find another way of doing this. What is the new method?

Comment: I added the 12.1 output to your post, to make it easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Szabolcs Amazing! The note you added is very interesting. Do you have an explanation for it?

Comment: The copy-paste note? This indicates that the bug is not in CountourPlot, but in graphics rendering. `CountourPlot` generates the correct `Graphics` expression with the correct `Dashing` directive. But the Mathematica front end does not render it correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Dashing` was extended in 12.3.  As such, you need to specify the cap type as part of the dashing spec. i.e.,

```
Dashing[{0, Medium, Medium, Medium}, 0, "Round"]
```

The capspec in `Dashing` overrides anything specified via `CapForm` in the directives list.

Comment: So, to clarify, even the default setting (i.e., not giving an explicit optional setting) would cause the override?

Comment: Correct.  The single argument form is just shorthand for `Dashing[arg, 0, "Butt"]`.